# Recursively Concatenate Strings in Array JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of type String in Javascript.
Eg: ["ab", "cd", "ef", "gh"]
This array is not fixed & is alphabetically ordered.

I want an output like this:

```
ab
abcd
abef
abgh
abcdef
abcdgh
abefgh
abcdefgh

cd
cdef
cdgh
cdefgh

ef
efgh
```

Comment: Please show us your effort first. Do you have some code where you tried to address your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this for creating the [power set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) of `x`:

```
function power(x) {
    var r = [""], // start with empty set/string
        l = 1;
    for (var i=0; i<x.length; l=1<<++i) // OK, l is just r[i].length, but this looks nicer :)
        for (var j=0; j<l; j++) {
            r.push(r[j].slice(0)); // copy
            r[j] += x[i];
        }
    return r;
}
```

Usage:

```
> power(["ab", "cd", "ef", "gh"])
["abcdefgh", "cdefgh", "abefgh", "efgh", "abcdgh", "cdgh", "abgh", "gh", "abcdef", "cdef", "abef", "ef", "abcd", "cd", "ab", ""]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Bergi. Power set did not come to my mind :P

Answer (score 0):

I agree with robin that you should try yourself first, but here it is (with help from lodash library):

```
function combos(arr) {
  if(arr.length <= 1) return arr
  return _.flatten(arr.map(function(key, index) {
    return [[key]].concat(
      combos(arr.slice(index+1))
      .map(function(combo) { return [key].concat(combo) })
    )
  }))
}

console.log(
  combos(["a", "b", "c", "d"])
  .map(function(arr) { return arr.join("")})
 )
```

http://jsbin.com/caxowuwuki/3/edit

Comment: Thanks Ollim..yes i will post from next time the code i tried to achieve this. It was good to learn about lodash library. New learning for me :)